java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<io.getstream.android.push.delegate.PushDelegateProvider> cannot be instantiated
I am encountering a runtime crash in my Android application during startup. The stack trace indicates an issue with the PushDelegateProvider class from the io.getstream.android package. Here is the error log:

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider
io.getstream.android.push.delegate.PushDelegateProvider:
java.lang.InstantiationException:
java.lang.Class<io.getstream.android.push.delegate.PushDelegateProvider>
cannot be instantiated at
android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7060)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6600)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:228) at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7438) at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:989) Caused
by: java.lang.InstantiationException:
java.lang.Class<io.getstream.android.push.delegate.PushDelegateProvider>
cannot be instantiated at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at
android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(AppComponentFactory.java:147)
at
androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateProvider(CoreComponentFactory.java:66)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7044)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6600)
at
android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6517)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:228)  at
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)  at
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)  at
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7438)  at
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:989)

What I Have Tried:

Checked the AndroidManifest.xml for any incorrect provider
declarations.
Ensured that all dependencies for io.getstream.android are
up-to-date.
Verified that the application is not using proguard or R8 rules that might strip or obfuscate the required classes.
Attempted to debug the issue but could not identify the exact cause.

My Questions:

What could cause a class to throw InstantiationException when it is used as a provider?

Are there specific configurations or dependencies required for
PushDelegateProvider from io.getstream.android?


Any guidance or pointers to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.
